# Monotouch: Do I have to dispose view?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

In my AppDelegate, I have a static event called LoggedOn.

My parent viewcontroller pushes a client viewcontroller.My client viewcontroller adds a delegate to the AppDelegate.LoggedOn event.

When I pop the client viewcontroller, the listner for the LoggedOn event is still listening .. emmmmm ... do I need to like dispose it or something?

I thought the whole client view was disposed when I pop'ed it?

Thanks!
Mojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to dispose of EventHandlers to global events like the LoggedOn event you have. These are called strong references and would prevent the ViewController that contains the delegate from being garbage collected.

I would do something like this in the ClientViewController:

```
public override void Dispose(bool disposing) 
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);

    if(disposing) {
        AppDelegate.LoggedOn -= Handle_LoggedOn;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem are indeed the references that are held through the event. As an alternative, in your client controller's ViewDidDisapper(), you can set your event to NULL which will kill all referring delegates. This can only be done from inside the class that is defining the event.

Comment: Thank you guys ... that helped. Only problem with Dispose is, that it's not fired right away, so the ViewDidDisapper is a great help. Thanks again! :)